# Detect anyone connecting network

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

Is there a way to detect someone connected to your network with Java? Like a event listener that will alert when someone is connected to your network?

For example I'm using this code

```
    String subnet = "192.168.1";
    int timeout = 1000;
    for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++) {
            String host = subnet + "." + i;
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)) {
                System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
            }
    }
```

But it has to check constantly all the time which is unefficient. Is there a broadcast or a signal that my pc receives when some other device connected to my Local Area Network?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not necessarily. The only component here that really knows such things is your router / switch.

Answer (score 0):

The method isReachable() uses ICMP ECHO and not every device has it enabled by default. If you are using Linux check out `netdiscover` this uses ARP I think (ARP is lower level than TCP/UDP, and with Java you can only create apps from TCP/UDP and above)